# Links showing up in different positions on different browsers.

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of links on the top and bottom of my page. I'll align the links will look aligned in Chrome but when I check out the page using Firefox the links are not in the same position they've moved down a few spots. This is driving me nuts.

[here is the link to my webpage](http://www.ernsteverything.com/ojk20)

The CSS for the bottom links

```
#navbot {
        color:silver;
        white-space:nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        position:relative;
        top:50px;
        left:36px;
        }   

#navbotS {
        color:silver;
        white-space:nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        position:relative;
        top:48px;
        left:44px;
        }

#navbotimg {
       top:0px;
       clear:both;
       float:left;
       position:relative;
       left:168px;
       }

#navbot2 {
       position:relative;
       min-width:800px;
       white-space:nowrap;
       color:silver;
       top: 10px;
       left:190px;
       }

#navbot3 {
       position:relative;
       min-width:1380px;
       white-space:nowrap;
       color:silver;
       top: -8px;
       left:158px;
      }

#mails li {
       float:right;
       list-style:none;
       margin:0 205px 0px -999px;
       }
```

The HTML

```
 <div id='navbot'> 
<a class="ex2"  href="#" >PERFORMANCE </a>
</div>
<div id='navbotS'> 
<a class="ex3"  href="#">SPORTSWEAR </a>         
</div>


  <div id ='navbotimg'>
  <img src="MAIN_IMAGES/red_line.png" width="8" height="60"> </div> 

  <div id ='navbot2'>
    <a class="ex1 various11" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/NIKE_SNOW.html">ZOOM FORCE ONE ///</a>            
    <a class="ex1 various1" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/MERCURIAL_SUPERFLY.html">MERCURIAL SUPERFLY ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various2" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/AIRMAX_MOTO.html">AIRMX MOTO BOOT ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various3" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/le-coq-joakim-noah.html">JOAKIM NOAH ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/NIKE_BMX.html">DUNK GYRIZO</a>                
  </div>

 <div id ='navbot3'>
      <ul id="mails">  
    <a class="ex1 various5" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/NIKE_AIRMAX_90.html">AIRMAX 90 ///</a>        
    <a class="ex1 various7" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/SUB_PAGE_CORTEZ_FLYMOTION.html" >CORTEZ FLY MOTION ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various"  href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/sub_page_org.html">ORIGINALS ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various8" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/SUB-PAGE-ARTHUR_ASH.html">ARTHUR ASHE ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various9" href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/SUB_PAGE_STUSSY_DUNK_TRAINER.html">STUSSY DUNK TRAINER ///</a> 
    <a class="ex1 various10"href="FOOTWEAR_SUB_PAGES/SUB_PAGE_AIR_MAX_1.html">AIR MAX I MAXIM</a>            
       <li><a class="mails" href="mailto:info@ernsteverything.com">INFO@ERNSTEVERYTHING.COM&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp</a></li>
       <li><a  href="mailto:info@ernsteverything.com"><img src="MAIN_IMAGES/mail_2.png" width="28" height="18" border="0"  ></a></li>              

       </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: They look the same to me (Opera, Firefox, Chrome).

Comment: @cimmanon If you look at the text at the bottom, FF and Chrome have slightly different size/spacing.

Comment: Every browser has their own method of rendering text.  There's nothing you can do about it.  If you absolutely want to control how text appears, then use an image.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Man that blows though